# A morphism-revealing category?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, computer-science, big-picture, universal-algebra

Categories of sets and functions can be considered as subcategories of **Set** but when considered as subcategories of the category **SubSet**, of pairs of sets with pairs $(X,S)$, $S\subseteq X$, as objects and functions $f:X\to Y$ with $f(S)\subseteq T$ as morphisms $(X,S)\to (Y,T)$, the morphisms of **SubSet** seems to reveal the form of the morphisms of the subcategories. Examples:

*Magmas*. $R\subseteq (X\times X)\times X$ (the composition). Morphisms are functions 
$\alpha:(X\times X)\times X\longrightarrow(X^\prime\times X^\prime)\times X^\prime$ such that 
$((x,y),z)\in R \Rightarrow \alpha((x,y),z)\in R^\prime$. Functions 
$\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3:X\longrightarrow X^\prime$ exists such that
$\alpha((x,y),z)=((\alpha_1(x),\alpha_2(y)),\alpha_3(z))$ and if $\alpha$ is such that $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3$, then $\alpha_1$ correspond to magma morphisms, $((x,y),z)\in R \Rightarrow ((\alpha_1(x), \alpha_1(y)),\alpha_1(z))\in R^\prime$. That is, 
$xy=z\Rightarrow\alpha_1(x)\alpha_1(y)=\alpha_1(z)$.

*Topological spaces*. $\tau\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$. Morphisms are 
functions $\mathcal{P}(X)\overset{\alpha}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{P}(X^\prime)$ such that 
$\mathcal{O}\in\tau \Rightarrow \alpha(\mathcal{O})\in \tau^\prime$. If there is a function
$f:X^\prime\longrightarrow X$ such that $\alpha = \mathcal{Q}(f)$, where $\mathcal{Q}$ is the contra-variant power set functor, this correspond to the condition 
$\mathcal{O}\in\tau\implies f^{-1}(\mathcal{O})\in\tau^\prime$.

Hence, studying subcategories of **Set** yields that the morphisms are functions, while studying subcategories of **SubSet** also yields additional information of the morphisms. So my questions are:

> Is this approach used in mathematics?
>   Has anyone published something about this?

Comment: I don't think it's not really true that concrete categories are subcategories of Set, in any sense that "subcategory" is usually meant.

Comment: @MikeShulman, are there severe problems looking at Grp as a subcategory of Set?

Comment: It just isn't what people mean by "subcategory".

Comment: @MikeShulman. OK! I've got a nice answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852811/problems-with-subcategories/1852839#1852839

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\SubSet}{\mathbf{SubSet}}\newcommand{\Set}{\mathbf{Set}}\newcommand{\Top}{\mathbf{Top}}$
$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}$

This general idea is definitely important in categorical logic and the theory of fibrations.  Let me rename your category **Pos** = **SubSet**.  There is an evident forgetful functor $p : \SubSet \to \Set$ given by the first projection, which has the important property that:

- $p$ is a bifibration

This means that there is an operation of pushing a subset $S \subseteq X$ along a morphism $f : X \to Y$ to obtain a subset $\mathbf{push}_fS \subseteq Y$ satisfying certain universal properties, as well as an operation of pulling a subset $T \subseteq Y$ along $f : X \to Y$ to obtain a subset $\mathbf{pull}_f T$ satisfying dual properties. In particular, these operations define functors between the *fibers* of $X$ and $Y$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{push}_f &: \SubSet_X \to \SubSet_Y \\
\mathbf{pull}_f &: \SubSet_Y \to \SubSet_X
\end{align*}
satisfying an adjunction $\mathbf{push}_f \dashv \mathbf{pull}_f$. In this case, of course, pushing and pulling are defined by image and inverse image:
$$
\mathbf{push}_fS = \{f(x) \mid x \in S\} \qquad
\mathbf{pull}_fT = \{x \mid f(x) \in T\}$$
But the definition of bifibration itself can be seen as a categorical abstraction of these basic operations on subsets.

Now, I think the idea that you are getting at (but correct me if I'm wrong) is that many concrete categories, seen as categories $C$ equipped with a forgetful functor $q : C \to \Set$, can be embedded into $p : \SubSet \to \Set$.  In particular, to take one of your examples, let $q : \Top \to \Set$ be the forgetful functor which returns the underlying set of a topological space.  This functor happens to be a fibration (given a topology on $Y$ and a function $f : X \to Y$ we can form the inverse image topology on $X$) but not quite a bifibration.  However, essentially as you observed, the concrete category of topological spaces can be studied using the $\SubSet$ bifibration. More precisely, there is a commuting diagram
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\Top^{op} & \ra{} & \SubSet  \\
 \da{q^{op}} & & \da{p} \\
 \Set^{op} & \ra{\mathcal{P}} & \Set
\end{array}
$$
that can be read as a *morphism of functors* $q^{op}\to p$, where $\mathcal{P} : \Set^{op} \to \Set$ is the contravariant powerset functor and $\Top^{op} \to \SubSet$ is the functor viewing a topological space $\tau$ over $X$ as a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$.  Moreover, this morphism $q^{op} \to p$ is full and faithful in the sense that for any fixed function $f : X \to X'$ and topological spaces $\tau,\tau'$ such that $q(\tau) = X,q(\tau') = X'$, then $f$ is a continuous function from $\tau$ to $\tau'$ (i.e., there is a morphism $\alpha : \tau \to \tau'$ in $\Top$ such that $q(\alpha) = f$) just in case the image of $\tau'$ under $\mathcal{P}(f)$ is included in $\tau$ (i.e., there is a morphism $\beta : \tau' \to \tau$ in $\SubSet$ such that $p(\beta) = \mathcal{P}(f)$).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "revealed morphism", but I _think_ the idea you are getting at is that many concrete categories can be embedded into the subset bifibration in a functorial way.  I added a bit more clarification to the answer.

Comment: @NoamZeilberger nice intro to bifibrations xD